# Can NFC enabled Android phones interact with each others?

Tags: android, nfc

I am just thinking about possibility to realize data sending/receiving between 2 or more NFC enabled smartphones. Is it possible or not? All I see about NFC is about interaction between NFC terminal/card and phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line one from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html

Provides access to Near Field Communication (NFC) functionality, allowing applications to read NDEF message in NFC tags. **A "tag" may actually be another device that appears as a tag.**

Hope this answers your question :-)

Comment: so NFC enabled android phone can be another device? How can it be justified?

Comment: NFC communication only works in a 10 - 15 cm radius so the possibility of accidentally discoverering a tag is minimal.

Comment: Check out Android's Ice Cream Sandwich update (where do they get these names) which has beefed up NFC support and will probably meet your requirements nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This is the nfc p2p mode. Android Beam is the "pre-installed" android nfc sharing app. BlackBerry Tag (O.S. 7.1) does the trick for BlackBerry. Nokia's nfc handsets already do it out of the box. I just don't know; What about tapping a nokia to an android, or android to blackberry, does it work? Feedback from users is hard to find yet.